# Hiding the form once data saved in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, html, onclick, hide

Hi I've done a lot of searching round but can't find anything concrete or that i can get working in my example.  Was wondering if anyone could help.  I've never used javascript before but have been asked for an assessment to code a piece of software to keep track of a score in  a ten pin bowling game.  I'm reading up as much as I can but there are a few things I'm still struggling on.  I've made a form for the players to input their names and I want to be able to hide the form once they have inputted their names, thus making the interface look less cluttered.  Have tried numerous methods but none seem to work for me, I've tried placing the form in a div and using an onClick event to hide the div but it doesn't seem to recognise the div etc, was looking for a few pointers, have taken my failed attempts out of the code to try and give a clear code for you to look at, thank you in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>

<style id="jsbin-css">

</style>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("formy").innerHTML="My First JavaScript Function";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="formy"><form>
<h1>Please enter player names!</h1>

<input id="player1" type="text" placeholder="Player 1" />

<input id="player2" type="text" placeholder="Player 2" />

<input id="player3" type="text" placeholder="Player 3" />

   <input id="player4" type="text" placeholder="Player 4" />

   <input id="player5" type="text" placeholder="Player 5" />

   <input id="player6" type="text" placeholder="Player 6" />
<input type="button" value="Save/Show" onclick="insert(),close.this", />
</form></p>
<div id="display"></div>
<script>
var titles  = [];
var names   = [];
var tickets = [];


var player1Input  = document.getElementById("player1");
var player2Input   = document.getElementById("player2");
var player3Input = document.getElementById("player3");
var player4Input = document.getElementById("player4");
var player5Input = document.getElementById("player5");
var player6Input = document.getElementById("player6");

var messageBox  = document.getElementById("display");

function insert ( ) {
 titles.push( player1Input.value );
 names.push( player2Input.value );
 tickets.push( player3Input.value );

 clearAndShow();
}

function clearAndShow () {
    // Show our output
  messageBox.innerHTML = "";

  messageBox.innerHTML += "<td>*" + player1Input.value + "<br/><td/>";
  messageBox.innerHTML += "*" + player2Input.value + "<br/>";
  messageBox.innerHTML += "*" + player3Input.value +"<br/>";
  messageBox.innerHTML += "*" + player4Input.value + "<br/>";
  messageBox.innerHTML += "*" + player5Input.value + "<br/>";
  messageBox.innerHTML += "*" + player6Input.value;

// Clear fields
titleInput.value = "";
nameInput.value = "";
ticketInput.value = "";

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place an id on the form. Hide the form on the button click. Test it [here](http://jsbin.com/ecutuk/1/).

```
<html>
<form id="b">
<textarea>hey</textarea>
<button onclick="hide(); return false;">click me</button>
</form>
<script>
function hide()
{
    document.getElementById('b').style.display='none';
}
</script>
</html>
```

You can get the element then set `style.display='none'` to hide it. I put in a `return false;` to keep the form from posting, and I added the function to a `<script>` for readability.

Comment: I've tested you example and it works but when I try and integrate it into my code it breaks the submission of the names collected, the hiding function works perfectly but its no use if I can't record the data they input, any ideas? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Save the data to what? If you call insert() before, it will push the data to your javascript arrays. You could alternatively call hide() at the end of your insert() method.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your functions, try this to hide everything in the p tag:

```
document.getElementById("formy").style.display = "none";
```

Also, I am not sure what you are trying to do on the onclick with 'close.this' - I would personally change it so you *just* have the function call (if there is an error in your onclick attribute, then the function may not be called):

```
<input type="button" value="Save/Show" onclick="insert()" />
```

Comment: I tired doing this and it didn't hide anything, also that close.this was something left over from a previous attempt.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Right, I tested your code on my own machine.
These following three lines refer to things not referred anywhere:
`titleInput.value = "";
nameInput.value = "";
ticketInput.value = "";`
If you don't correct that, then any code beyond those lines won't get run. It was my mistake on hiding the 'p' tag - the 'p' tag doesn't hold the form like a div would. Following the example by the person above, if I give your form an id, and then change .style.display to none on it, then I am left with the list of player names. Be careful to leave your div with the id 'display' outside of any element you hide.